# Que le ocurre a la instalación de Visual Studio que no avanza?

Tags: visual-studio

[image: Pasa en cualquier version de VS.Tengo Windows 8.1, instale el update manualmente y aun no funciona]

La instalación de Visual Studio de cualquier versión no avanza y se queda aplicando el windows update KB2999226 durante muchísimas horas. Intenté instalar la actualizacion de manera manual, pero aun así la instalación del IDE no ha sido posible.

Comment: con manual te refieres bajando el iso? si no, intenta bajar el iso en vez de exe

Comment: Generalmente, aunque sea una computadora con bastante memoria y procesador, el Visual Studio tarde bastante tiempo en instalarse. Además también dependerá de la conexión a internet que tengas.

Comment: Alanna, considero que es importante verifiques tu conexión eso podría ser el problema, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo lo siguiente:

1. Suspendé la instalación de Visual.
2. Baja el archivo de actualización desde la página de windows desde acá https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49093
3. Instalá el paquete de manera independiente y después ejecutá el instalador.

**Nota:** Si bajando ese archivo intenta aplicar el uptade nuevamente durante la instalación, es porque necesita otra versión del update. Podés fijarte acá otras versiones y bajar la que necesites.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/2999226

Por ejemplo, la versión de 64 bits.